# How to avoid .replace replacing a word that was already replaced

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace, reverse

Given a string, I have to reverse every word, but keeping them in their places.

I tried:

```
def backward_string_by_word(text):
    for word in text.split():
        text = text.replace(word, word[::-1])        
    return text
```

But if I have the string `Ciao oaiC`, when it try to reverse the second word, it's identical to the first after beeing already reversed, so it replaces it again. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`s.replace(x, y)` is not the correct method to use here:

It does two things:

1. *find* `x` in `s`
2. *replace* it with `y`

But you do not really *find* anything here, since you already *have* the word you want to replace. The problem with that is that it starts searching for `x` from the beginning at the string each time, not at the position you are currently at, so it finds the word you have already replaced, not the one you want to replace next.

The simplest solution is to collect the reversed words in a list, and then build a new string out of this list by concatenating all reversed words. You can concatenate a list of strings and separate them with spaces by using `' '.join()`.

```
def backward_string_by_word(text):
    reversed_words = []
    for word in text.split():
        reversed_words.append(word[::-1])
    return ' '.join(reversed_words)
```

If you have understood this, you can also write it more concisely by skipping the intermediate list with a generator expression:

```
def backward_string_by_word(text):
    return ' '.join(word[::-1] for word in text.split())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use join in one line plus generator expression:

```py
text = "test abc 123"
text_reversed_words = " ".join(word[::-1] for word in text.split())
```

Answer (score 0):

Splitting a string converts it to a list. You can just reassign each value of that list to the reverse of that item. See below:

```
text = "The cat tac in the hat"

def backwards(text):
    split_word = text.split()
    for i in range(len(split_word)):
        split_word[i] = split_word[i][::-1]
    return ' '.join(split_word)

print(backwards(text))
```